# Create table in Excel from messy text

Tags: r, excel, text

I would like to clean up my text data and turn it into an excel table for further usage in R. I have managed to get my messy data into a text document with 500 lines corresponding to 500 observations. They have a structure similar to this:

```
Name$Johnny Cash$Birth$1932$Gender$Male$Occupation$Singer$Death$2003
Name$Elvis Presley$Birth$1935$Gender$Male$Death$1977$Occupation$Singer
Name$June Carter$Birth$1929$Gender$Female$Occupation$Singer$Death$2003
```

This is how it should look like in the end:

[image]

I have started by using the "text to column"-function from Excel. If the rows would be completely similar, I could then use these formulas:

```
=IF(ISODD(COLUMN(A1)),A1,"")
=IF(ISEVEN(COLUMN(B1)),B1,"")
```

which would make my table look like this:
[image]

However, the data I have is not that ordered  - sometimes, the order of entries differs (first death, then occupation), sometimes, a category is missing, such as in this example: 
[image]

I do not know how to go further from here - is there a macro in Excel that could help me, or would I be better of trying to achieve this in R in some way? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could organize your text file as a csv file (comma separated values) and easily open it in Excel or R.

The text file would look like the example below. As you can see, every row is a subject:

```
"name", "birth", "gender", "occupation","death"
"Johnny Cash", 1932, "male", "singer", 2003
```

To re-format your text file into csv, you could just replace e.g. "name$" with a " in all lines. Replace $birth$ with ", ". You have to be a little bit creative to get the commas and citations marks at the right place, but it can be done. Finally add a first row containing the headers, i.e.:

```
 "name", "birth", "gender", "occupation","death"
```

Comment: The original file is actually in Chinese, which is where the $ comes from. Of course I can change the $ to commas, however, that problem is that if I compare lines 2 and 3, it would be once  containing information in this order "name", "birth", "gender", "occupation","death" and once in this order "name", "birth", "gender", "death", "occupation"

Comment: Ah, I see, did not notice that the data is not in order. Is this a standard notation you are using, and if yes, what is it called?

If it's not, I guess it would take some bash scripting or other programming to solve the problem.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with standard notation? Pardon my ignorance!

Comment: No worries, do other people use this way of organizing text files? If yes, there should be a name for this style (e.g. $ separated file). You could then google or ask how to convert "$ separated file"  to csv or similar. If you made this up yourself, there is probably no built-in solution. You would have to do some custom programming to get it in right shape.

Comment: The original data comes from a database for bibliographical data from China. I have already contacted customer service, but I doubt that they have a solution for me. Where would you recommend me to do custom programming?

Comment: I am not a programmer myself, but think any programming language, like Python for instance, could be used to solve your problem. Maybe you can find someone at your institution or equivalent (don't know in what capacity you are trying to solve the problem).